# Varnish error: /etc/init.d/varnish: 50: /etc/default/varnish: -p: not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, varnish, magento

I've installed Varnish on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and want to use it with my Magento shop.

Information:

- Magento 1.9.0.1
- Varnish Cache 3.0.5
- Magento Turpentine 0.6.0

I've followed the **[installation instructions](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Installation)** for Magento Turpentine and point 2 reads as follows:

> You'll need to make Varnish start up with the `-p esi_syntax=0x2 option`

Here's what my `/etc/default/varnish` file looks like:

```
# Configuration file for varnish

START=yes

NFILES=131072

MEMLOCK=82000

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m" \
             -p esi_syntax=0x2
```

When doing `sudo service varnish restart` I get

```
/etc/init.d/varnish: 50: /etc/default/varnish: -p: not found
/etc/init.d/varnish: 50: /etc/default/varnish: -p: not found
 * Stopping HTTP accelerator varnishd
   ...done.
/etc/init.d/varnish: 50: /etc/default/varnish: -p: not found
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd
   ...done.
```

What's causing this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a new option but forgot to move the closing quotation mark to the end of the last option.

So check

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m" \ # <<< Currently here
             -p esi_syntax=0x2
```

It should look like this

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m \
             -p esi_syntax=0x2" # <<< Should be here
```